# Approximating $\sqrt{2}$ by Pythagorean triples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, approximation, radicals, pythagorean-triples

I am trying to find sequence of Pythagorean triples $(x_{n}, y_{n}, z_{n})\in\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ such that $x_{n}/y_{n}\rightarrow 1$. This way, both $z_{n}/x_{n}$ and $z_{n}/y_{n}$ would converge to $\sqrt{2}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I am aware there are various other ways of approximating $\sqrt{2}$ by rational numbers such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240420), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60325), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291168), but none of these give me a way to generate Pythagorean triples in the way I desire. I am wondering if there is an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with the (old, popular) technique for constructing pythagorean triples by intersecting a unit circle with a line at two places, (-1, 0) and anywhere else in the positive-positive quadrant?

Comment: Just to clarify : You want to create large pythogearean triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a\approx b$ WITHOUT using the value of $\sqrt{2}$ or any other closely related value. Is this right ?

Comment: @Peter I suppose yes. Preferably it'd give an algorithm to approximate/find $\sqrt{2}$ without knowing the value of $\sqrt{2}$ ahead of time (if that's what you were asking).

Comment: @DanielV No. (I may have encountered it before, but probably forgot.)

Comment: @MaximalIdeal Well if you learn that technique for generating pythagorean triples (there's a million youtube videos explaining it), your question is equivalent to the line approaching the intersection at $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2)$

Comment: I am not sure whether the below answers are hidden uses of sequences converging to $\sqrt{2}$ (the one I commented is definitely circular). But considering that even the Heron method establishes excellent approximations of $\sqrt{2}$ , this new approach to approximate it has little merit anyway. Far more interesting is the other way round , namely to find triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a\approx b$ with the help of $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @Peter but it is not circular. The OP knows how to generate rational approximations for $\sqrt{2}$. All I did was explain how to turn one of them into another approximation which is also of the form the OP wanted. I then gave a concrete example where I generated a rational approximation from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We begin with Euclid's formula for generating Pythagorean triples, shown here as

$$A=m^2-k^2 \qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2$$
The $\,mk\,$ values for a series of triples where $\,|B-A|=1\,$ are contiguous [Pell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell_number), i.e.
$\,\big\{1,2,5,12,29,70,169,\cdots\big\}$ and may be generated by the following funcions:
$$ m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\qquad
 k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$
For example
\begin{align*}
m_1&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{2} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=2
& k_1= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^1 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^1}{2\sqrt{2}}=1\\ 
m_2&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{3} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=5
& k_2= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^2}{2\sqrt{2}}=2\\ 
m_3&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{4} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{4}}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 
& k_3= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^3 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^3}{2\sqrt{2}}=5\\
m_4&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{5} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}=29
&k_4= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^4 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^4}{2\sqrt{2}}=12\\
 \end{align*}

The values grow quickly and exceed $\,15\,$ digits when
$\,n>19.\quad$ Here is a series sample
\begin{align*}
F(2,1)&=(3,4,5)\\
F(5,2)&=(21,20,29)\\
F(12,5)&=(119,120,169)\\
F(29,12)&=(697,696,985)\\
F(70,29)&=(4059,4060,5741)\\
F(169,70)&=(23661,23660,33461)\\
F(408,169)&=(137903,137904,195025)\\
F(985,408)&=(803761,803760,1136689)\\
\end{align*}
With $\,n\,$ sufficiently high, we can generate a Pythagorean triple where $C/A\text{ and }C/B\,$ are both arbitrarily close to $\,\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Very interesting (+1). I looked at the first few iterates and it coincides with my example (now with $q_{1,0}=2$ and $q_{2,0}=3$) as well as with J. W. Tanner's example. I wonder if we could prove this.

Comment: @Numerical Disintegration  Another way of generating these triples may be what you are suggesting and comes from Wacław Sierpiński: Pythagorean triangles, 
THE SCRPTA MATHEMATICA STUDIES Number NINE,
GRADUATE SCHOOL OF SCIENCE YESHIVA  UNIVERSITY, NEW YORK, 1962, pp.  17-22 
with a starting "seed" of $T_0=(0,0,1)$.
$$T_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+1\qquad  B_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+2 \qquad C_{n+1}=4A_n+3C_n+2$$
$$T_1=(3,4,5)\quad T_2=(20,21,29)\quad T_3=(119,120,168)\quad T_4=(696,697,985)\quad ...$$

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to find sequence of Pythagorean triples $(x_{n}, y_{n}, z_{n})\in\mathbb{Z}^{3}$ such that $x_{n}/y_{n}\rightarrow 1$.

Start with $(x,x+1,z)=(3,4,5)$.

Given $x^2+(x+1)^2=z^2$, it follows that $(3x+2z+1)^2+(3x+2z+2)^2=(4x+3z+2)^2$.

So take $x_{n+1}=3x_n+2z_n+1$, $y_{n+1}=x_{n+1}+1$, and $z_{n+1}=4x_n+3z_n+2$

to get a sequence you desire.

Comment: See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3725577/when-the-sum-of-squares-of-two-consecutive-integers-is-again-a-perfect-square)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate Pythagorean triplets as follows:

Take two integers, $q_1$ and $q_2$. Then define $p_1 = q_1 +q_2$ and $p_2 = 2q_1 +q_2$. Taking $a = 2 q_1 p_1$, $b=q_2 p_2$, $c = q_1 p_2 + q_2 p_1$ it holds that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples#Method_III).

For $a_n/b_n\to 1$ we require to find $q_{1,n}$, $q_{2,n}$ such that $2q_{1,n}^2/q_{2,n}^2\to 1$.

That is $q_{2,n}/q_{1,n}\to \sqrt{2}$. But we can take any rational sequence that tends to $\sqrt{2}$. Taking $q_{2,n}$ and $q_{1,n}$ to be the numerator and denominator of such a sequence yields the result.

**Edit:**

After the criticism from Peter and the down vote (both of which I think were a bit unfair) here is a concrete example.

Let us consider
$q_{1,0}=2$, $q_{2,0}=3$ and take
$$ q_{1,n+1} = q_{1,n} + q_{2,n},$$
$$ q_{2,n+1} = 2q_{1,n} + q_{2,n}.$$
This is a rational approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ taken from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240420/show-that-if-m-n-is-a-good-approximation-of-sqrt2-then-m2n-mn-is-be) example given by the OP.

Then we can take
$$ a_n = 2 q_{1,n} q_{1,n+1}\quad;\quad b_n = q_{2,n}q_{2,n+1}\quad;\quad c_n = q_{1,n}q_{2,n+1} + q_{2,n}q_{1,n+1}.$$

Comment: This is circular since the author wants to approximate $\sqrt{2}$ with the pythagorean triples. Here we need approximations to get the "good" triples.

Comment: I don't follow. Take any approximation and you can generate one that is of the form the OP wants. If you want 'an' approximation there are a heap of resources for this.

Comment: @Peter Well nonetheless this post contains valuable info. I'll think about it.

Comment: Seriously? Why the down vote?